# in R, delete the vectors from a data frame that meet a condition

Tags: r

I have a data frame (`df`) in r and I want to remove all the columns that are invariant (have the same number)

```
df <- read.table(text = "1 2 3 1 1 3 1 2 3 1 2 3

                 1 1 1 1 3 2 1 2 1 1 3 1

                 1 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 1 2 3

                 1 1 3 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 3", header = FALSE)

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
1  1  2  3  1  1  3  1  2  3   1   2   3
2  1  1  1  1  3  2  1  2  1   1   3   1
3  1  3  1  1  2  2  1  1  3   1   2   3
4  1  1  3  1  1  2  1  2  1   1   2   3
```

and keep the columns that are variant

```
 V2 V3 V5 V6 V8 V9 V11 V12
  2  3  1  3  2  3   2   3
  1  1  3  2  2  1   3   1
  3  1  2  2  1  3   2   3
  1  3  1  2  2  1   2   3
```

Comment: `Filter(var, df1)`

Answer (score 0):

`df[, !duplicated(t(df))]` gives you non-duplicated columns

```
  V1 V2 V3 V5 V6 V8 V9 V11 V12
1  1  2  3  1  3  2  3   2   3
2  1  1  1  3  2  2  1   3   1
3  1  3  1  2  2  1  3   2   3
4  1  1  3  1  2  2  1   2   3
```